# why does the same request keep hitting my server even though I didn't call the endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, https, server, response

I have a question to something I tried to resolve but it seems to keep happening. I have a simple server endpoint `/example` and I call that endpoint from a curl `123.45.678.901/example` and the server runs a function and returns something to me and then I `res.end()`, but I noticed that after a while the endpoint is hit again even though I didn't call it and I can see on the terminal where the server is open one of my console.logs appears. This is the code

```
const express = require ("express");
const app = express();
const port = 80;

//middleware function
const authenticateUser = (req,res,next) => {
  console.log("header w/ access_token sent in:", req.header("token"))
  request.get({
   url: [url here were I authenticate the token they sent me]
  }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body){
       if (err) { 
         res.send("Authentication failed, please check your access_token");
         res.end();
       }
      console.log("Authentication has been cleared");
    next()

  })
}

//here I tell express to use my middleware always
app.use(authenticateUser);

app.get("/example", (req,res) =>{
             console.log("in /example endpoint");
             (some function being called here that returns something to the client)
             res.end();

})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}`));
```

this is what I see when the ghost call is made to the server, I know I didn't call the endpoint because if I had the `undefined` I see there would show a token I pass in through Headers in the cURL:

[image]

Comment: Where do you log the `header w/ access_token sent in:` string? Can you show us the code?

Comment: We need to see more code, specifically the code that is doing the logging you show.

Comment: edited my code to show a middleware function that I wasn't previously showing. other than that, the "function" I'm mentioning inside of the endpoint is just a function that runs a file

Comment: the middleware function is where I'm logging `header w/ access_token sent in:` message

Comment: Post the code where you actually install `authenticateUser`. The code right now doesn't call `authenticateUser` ever, so we need to see the actual code.

Comment: oh I'm so sorry, I just forgot to add the `app.use` line! @AndreasPizsa

Comment: OK; so, your authentication method gets called for every request for any URL, including requests for things like favicon.ico, robots.txt etc; I guess an easy way for you to find out what’s triggering this is to just also log `req` (or parts of it), which will give you the path, user agent, ip address, etc

Comment: As a side note, I recommend using [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) instead of `request`, it’s a lot leaner, frees you from callback hell and gives you Promises :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202364/discussion-between-carol-gonzalez-and-andreaspizsa).